# images in tableViewCells that are in Sections (swift 3- Xcode 8.3.2)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, intersection

Hi I have a table view And want to make it like a picture below

[image: TableView with Sections]

here is the code that I used ( the problem is that I can't see the picture of each cells  :

```
var menuImage = ["Add.png" , "Menu.png" , "Add.png" , "Add.png" , "Add.png" , "Add.png" ]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel!.text = listSetting[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "IRANSans", size: 14)
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: menuImage[indexPath.row])

    return cell

}
```

the second problem Is that I want to detect which cells has pressed here is the code that I used But Didn't work :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt listSetting: IndexPath) {

        print("Remove Adds")


        if listSetting.section == 1 && listSetting.row == 1{
            //Code to implement View Controller to remove adds
            print("Cell4 pressed")
        }
```

Comment: I could see you are using 4-5 sections in UITableView. You need to array of arrays in your menuImage array so as to populate images using UITableView Section and Row number

Comment: I used Array for sections and Rows (My Codes Are so Large for this reason I wrote some of them here) But I have Two Arrays  one for sections and another one for Cells  var listSetting =[[ "A" , "B" ] , [ "C" , "D" , "E" ] , ["F"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Main.storyboard, select the cell and in the Size Inspector change the Row Height to 140 (as per your need-Check in storyboard) 
Now in viewDidLoad()type this code,use UITableViewAutomaticDimension method:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140 //as per your need
```

and mention this reloadData().

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

More checkout below link:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells